# vmware esx pxe boot guest wds

Tags: vmware-esx, pxe-boot

I have WDS set up to PXE boot for physical hosts in my network, but when I try to boot from a newly created VM on an ESX server, I get the following error:

```
 PXE-E53: No boot filename received

 PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE Rom
 Operating System not found
```

Is there some trick to getting PXE boot to work on a VM?  Is there a particular way to set up the networking?  Perhaps something needs to be reconfigured on the PXE server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would post what the solution turned out to be.  WDS PXE service had a "wait time before responding" that someone had set to 30 seconds.  I noticed that vmware ESX vms only polls PXE for maybe 10 seconds.  ... they just weren't waiting long enough.

I lowered the "wait time before responding" setting, and all is well.